# Object Not Found xamp

Tags: php, xampp

i have PHP Application which is running perfectly on my hosting Server, but when i try to run my application on xamp (Localhost) it give me Error Below

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
>   you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.35 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.11

my Code is Below

```
$allowed_files = array('login.php');
$current_file = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

$root = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
DEFINE('SITE_URL', $root);
DEFINE('STORE_ID', $_SESSION['admin_auth']);
DEFINE('ROLE_ID', $_SESSION['Role']);
DEFINE('USER_ID', $_SESSION['UserID']);
DEFINE('APP_PATH', (str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'include', '', __DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
```

I am able to login and it give me URL /list.php but when i select option from list.php file there is another Redirect code which pick link below code is in last line of my list.php file

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-transparent cClick" href="<?php print SITE_URL . $row->CompanyID; ?>/index.php" >Access</a>
```

Comment: Did you check your PHP version?

Comment: send the manual and after clicking url ?

Comment: PHP version is 7.2 , After Clicking on Access Button on list.php file i get this error